# next-auth.session-token invalid signature on jwt.io

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth

Did someone encounter similar errors when trying to decode your next-auth.session-token on jwt.io? I followed a video and tried copy my session token to jwt.io to see it, but all i get is an error saying "Invalid signature"

What did i miss here?
**[...nextauth].tsx file**

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
session: {
strategy: "jwt",
},
providers: [
CredentialsProvider({
  type: "credentials",
  credentials: {},
  authorize(credentials, req) {
    const { email, password } = credentials as {
      email: string;
      password: string;
    };

    //Perform your login logic here
    //Find out user from db

    if (email !== "john@gmail.com" || password !== "1234") {
      throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
    }

    //If everything is fine
    return { id: "1234", name: "John Doe", email: "john@gmail.com" };
  },
}),
],
pages: {
signIn: "/auth/signin",
},
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Cookie image
[image]
jwt io image
[image]

Comment: Your token seems to be not a signed JWT/JWS but an encrypted token (JWE). The site jwt.io can't deal with JWE. And even if you had a normal JWT, you did not provide any key or secret under "VERIFY SIGNATURE", so it would be impossible to verify the signature.

Comment: Ahaaaaa makes sense, so i have to decrypt it with my secret and then result should be able to be displayed on JWT.io?

Comment: No, a JWE has a different structure (5 segments vs. 3 segments JWT). You can try [this online decoder](https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the Cookie "next-auth.session-token", which is generated by next-auth and encrypt by your secret.

we still need to descrypt it before usage.

Comment: how do u decrypt it (jwe)